# Binarysearch unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Hopefully someone knows the answer to this Java-Certification question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String[] sa = {"d", "c", "a", "b" };
 int x = Arrays.binarySearch(sa, "b");
 Arrays.sort(sa);
 int y = Arrays.binarySearch(sa, "b");
 System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

Which two results are possible? (Choose two.)
A)  7 0 
B)  7 1
C)  7 3
D) -1 0
E) -1 1
F) -1 3

The only true answer is E) -1 1, because if you play through the binary-search-algorithm this is the only possible output. But they want me to choose two...
So the second one have to be B) 7 1 then, because the second binarySearch in the sorted array will always return `1`.

So my Question is, why is B) 7 1 a possible result?
More specific: How is it possible, that the first binarySearch in the unsorted array returns 7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like they deceive you))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a trick question. The results of binary search on an unsorted array are undefined, as per documentation:

> The array **must** be sorted (as by the sort method, above) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

This means in particular that any number, including seven, is fair game.

The results on a sorted one are well-defined: you'll get a `1`. As if by magic, there are only two pairs that end in `1` on the list of answers, so `B` and `E` is the choice the examiners expect you to make.

Comment: The API docs do specify that the array is searched "using the binary search algorithm". Thus, the internal operation of the method is documented to some extent. I don't believe there exists any definition of "the binary search algorithm" that would allow a return value of 7, regardless of how the array is sorted. So unless one is supposed to treat that part of the API docs as essentially meaningless, I think that this particular certification question is flawed. (Furthermore, depending on how the implementation rounds the midpoint--something _not_ documented), the first call might return 3.)

Comment: @TedHopp It is possible to code an algorithm that detects inconsistencies while performing the binary search, for example, by verifying that the item at the tentative midpoint is always less than or equal to the item at the right end of the interval, and is also greater than or equal to the item at the left end of the current interval. An algorithm that returns a randomly chosen number `7` upon detecting an unsorted array would behave according to the specification, although I do agree that such implementation would be highly unlikely, to say the least.

Comment: I don't know of any published definition of binary search that behaves that way (or one that even does such checking). When the docs specify that a method implements a particular, well-defined algorithm, I don't think we are free to reinvent the algorithm willy-nilly. The binary search algorithm _assumes_ the array is sorted, and hence does not specify what happens when the assumption fails. But the behavior for any _specific_ unsorted array is actually very well defined (modulo how `first` and `last` are initialized and how rounding is done for the midpoint guess). This cert question stinks.

Comment: This answer is not always true.  I'll post an example below.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably supposed to stick to the documentation, not to your knowledge of how binary search works in general. The API docs are pretty clear on using `Array.binarySearch` on unsorted arrays: "If it is not sorted, the results are undefined."

In other words, if the array is not sorted, the result is not required to follow any rules. From the implementation of binary search you may know that the result cannot exceed the array length. However, that's implementation detail. You cannot rely on that.

Comment: So despite the fact, that the result of the usorted binarysearch will always be -1 in this case, they want me to say that also 7 is a possible result because the documentation says the result is undefined? Well than, so that bastards realy want to trick me ...
However thanks for your answers! :)

Comment: That's exactly the point. The implementation may ensure that the result is always either -1 or the actual index. The documentation does not guarantee this for unsorted arrays, thus you must not rely on it. Ok, a binary search implementation will hardly ever change drastically.

Comment: Consider this made-up case: A sort algorithm for lists expects the list to implement `RandomAccess` to be stable. According to the documentation stability is not guaranteed for lists not implementing that. At first the same algorithm may internally be used for such lists, at the expense of being very slow. Later, to speed things up, a fork is added to apply a different algorithm for lists not implementing `RandomAccess`. That new sort is not stable, but if you relied on that before (even though the docs never gave that guarantee), your own code will be broken.

Comment: "_if the array is not sorted, the result is not required to follow any rules_" -- Not quite correct. The docs also say that the array is searched "using the binary search algorithm". The binary search algorithm is well defined and while the results of the API call are "undefined" (as they are for the binary search algorithm in the abstract), this is not the same thing as saying that the results are "random and arbitrary".

Comment: @Ted: There are at least two ways to implement Binary Search. One stops if the item is found early "by accident", the other continues to subdivide the search space until one element is left. Both have a slim chance of finding stuff in an unsorted array, but they will succeed in different cases. Instead of plain Binary Search, it's also possible to use a different index than the middle to divide the search space.

Comment: @Wormbo - If you don't use the middle, it's a stretch to call it "the binary search algorithm". In either case, the algorithm never generates an out-of-bounds index as the answer. That's the main point--when you say "the binary search algorithm" there are at least _some_ rules, even if the details (and the results) vary according to the implementation.

Comment: @Ted But that's not the point. The documentation is written this way to tell you that you cannot depend on any specific behavior if the array is not sorted. The behavior for that case may change in the future in the unlikely event of an implementation change.